# How to remove pattern from line but return what remains?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

If I run `ip addr sho | grep 9000` it returns the interface that I need quick stats for:

`eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000`

However, I'd like to learn how to make this grep command return a shorter line without the unnecessary details, like:

`eth3: mtu 9000 state UP`

Can this be accomplished with certain parameters applied to the grep command?

Comment: This is more of a task for [tag:sed] or [tag:awk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` solution.  Look for a line with eth, followed by a number, followed by a :, and then print the relevant columns.

```
$ ip a s | awk '/eth[0-9]*:/{print $2,$4,$5,$8,$9}'
eth0: mtu 1460 state UP
$
```

`sed` solution, although someone's going to point out there's a sweeter + shorter way.

```
$ ip a s | sed -n 's/^.*\(eth[0-9]*:\).*\(mtu [0-9]*\).*\(state [A-Z]*\).*/\1 \2 \3/p'
eth0: mtu 1460 state UP
$
```

`grep` + `cut` solution.

```
$ ip a s | grep -E 'eth[0-9]+:' | cut -f2,4,5,8,9 -d" "
eth0: mtu 1460 state UP
$
```

Comment: The sweeter way is probably something like `ip -j a s | jq -r '.[] | select(.ifname  | contains("eth")) | [.ifname, .mtu, .operstate] | @tsv'`